# Passing value into your parameter (rs.exe) by stored procudure

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a situation here where I have a deployed rdl file in the reporting server. The rdl file in question has a parameter.

I am using the rs.exec component to execute the report; whenever I remove the parameter from the rdl file, I successfully run the report from the stored procedure. When I add the parameter, all I keep getting is

```
\\server\R\subfolder\working\inputfile\example.batK00WE is not recognized as an internal or external operable program or batch file.
```

Here is what I did: I created a .rss file in VB (Please see code below)

```
 Public Sub Main()

    TRY

     DIM historyID as string = Nothing
     DIM deviceInfo as string = Nothing
     DIM extension as string = Nothing
     DIM encoding as string
     DIM mimeType as string = "application/Excel"
     DIM warnings() AS Warning = Nothing
     DIM streamIDs() as string = Nothing
     DIM results() as Byte

     rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
     rs.LoadReport(REPORTSERVER_FOLDER, historyID)

     results = rs.Render(FORMAT, deviceInfo, extension, mimeType, encoding, warnings, streamIDs)

     DIM stream As FileStream = File.OpenWrite(FILENAME)
     stream.Write(results, 0, results.Length)
     stream.Close()

    Catch e As IOException
      Console.WriteLine(e.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Afterwards... I wrote batch file that utilizes the rs.exec. Please see below:

```
"\\server\R\subfolder\working\app\rs.exe" -i \\server\R\subfolder\working\inputfile\coo.rss -s "http://server/ReportServer_MSSQLSERVER2" -v FILENAME="\\server\R\subfolder\working\inputfile\file.csv" -v REPORTSERVER_FOLDER="/FILE_REPORT/FILE" -t  -v FORMAT="EXCEL" -e Exec2005
```

If you see the above script the rs.exec utilizes the path of the report server etc.

Finally I created a stored procedure that will run the report on the server and pass into the server the parameter value.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[test_sproc]
@ProcessID varchar(50)

AS

DECLARE @cmdsql varchar(1000)
Declare @id  varchar(50)
Set     @id=@SID
Set     @cmdsql= '"\\server\R\subfolder\working\inputfile\example.bat"' + @id
exec master..xp_CMDShell @cmdsql
```

So here is my question is: How do I pass the parameter value from stored procedure to the report server? Where did I go wrong with my code?

Comment: You have concatonated the name of the bat file and the param value. So xp_cmdshell indeed cannot find that file name. I don't know how to pass parameters to a report with rs.exe, but start with getting the parameter properly passed to the bat file. Then get the bat file to pass the value to the rss script

Comment: @billinkc: Anyinput sir?